Why does Micropython WLAN on ESP not connect
I have a function in the boot sequence that is working with the same data as the following code. The only difference is that I have made a class out of the stuff here. and now there are always an error if I try to connect.
OSError: Wifi Internal Error
The code is:
class WLAN(network.WLAN):
  def __init__(self, lcd: lcd_object, data: data_object):
    super().__init__(network.STA_IF)
    self._data = data
    self._count_error = 0
    
  
  def run(self):
    # activate the interface
    if self._data.data["WlanEnable"] == "On" and not self.isconnected():
      self.active(True)
      self.connect("some_ssid", "some_key")

The SSID and Key sho the correct values if I print them to the console. So the data transfer itself from the data dictionary is working.
I tried several approaches even very basic ones. I think something goes wrong with the class itself or the super().init:
